# How to redefine Spring bean from default-synchronization-context.xml

Tags: java, spring, alfresco

In Alfresco 5.0d, many Spring context XML files are packaged inside JAR files. For example, the file `default-synchronization-context.xml` is contained in

```
tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/alfresco-repository-5.0.d.jar
```

How do I **redefine a Spring bean** that is defined in this XML file and is used in the "Synchronization" subsystem?

I've tried to put an altered version of this XML file into

```
tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/subsystems/Synchronization/default
```

which has no effect. The Spring context is not even loaded. Putting it directyl into

```
tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension
```

at least causes the Spring context to be loaded. But any bean redefined in it only is used in the Authentication(!) subsystem but **not** in the Synchronization subsystem.

What is the correct way to redefine a Spring bean of the Synchronization subsystem?

**Edit:**

As requested in a comment I add a property from `tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties`:

```
authentication.chain=ldap1:ldap1,alfrescoNtlm1:alfrescoNtlm
```

Comment: can you tell me what exactly you want to achieve?ldap synchronization can be defined in alfresco-global.properties.

Comment: @KrutikJayswal I know. But I need to change the implementation of `ChainingUserRegistrySynchronizer` in a way that can not be achived by just setting properties.

Comment: can you updated question by adding properties which are defined in alfresco-global.properties..specially authentication.chain

Comment: Done. What relevance can the chain have for the Spring context loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the `authentication.chain` property which defines , from where we are fetching property file.

Below URL is description of that.
    alfresco/extension/subsystems/Authentication/alfrescoNtlm/alfrescoNtlm1/mychanges.properties

If you have noticed that **alfrescoNtlm1** folder than,this folder name must match with the property value **ldap1:ldap1,*alfrescoNtlm1*:alfrescoNtlm**.(See Italic text)

In case of context file you can define context file in same folder with the name suffix as ***-context**

For more info, read content of below link,specially spring bean section.

https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_Subsystems#Spring_Beans

If this does not work,than disable existing one and create new file, inside extension folder.by seeing that file(default-synchronization-context.xml) i can say that its nothing but cronjob which fires after some interval, you need to define one cron job and some other configuration.

Comment: Are you sure this applies to the *Synchronization* subsystem? I know this strcuture from the *Authentication* subsystem.

Comment: see updated answer.and one more thing I am not sure you know this or not  but if you see userRegistrySynchronizer bean is referenced in syncTrigger

Comment: The path is `tomcat/shared/classes/extension/subsystem/Synchronization/default/default`.